# Getting error when trying to run SQL statement in a oracle function

Tags: oracle, plsql

```
create or replace function auditif
return number as
l_filter_count  NUMBER;
begin
 EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'EXPLAIN PLAN FOR ' || SYS_CONTEXT('USERENV','CURRENT_SQL');
select count(*)
     into l_filter_count
     from table(dbms_xplan.display(format=>'PREDICATE'))
     where (plan_table_output like '% - filter(%' OR plan_table_output like '% - access(%')
     and plan_table_output not like '%SYS_AUDIT(%';
     dbms_output.put_line(l_filter_count);
if  (SUBSTR(UPPER(sys_context('userenv','CLIENT_PROGRAM_NAME')),1,3)='SQL' AND l_filter_count=0)
or 
(SUBSTR(UPPER(sys_context('userenv','CLIENT_PROGRAM_NAME')),1,4)='TOAD' AND l_filter_count=0)
then return 1;
else return 0; 
end if;
end;
/
```

I have called this function inside a DBMS_FGA policy for enable audit conditionally

```
begin
  DBMS_FGA.ADD_POLICY(
    OBJECT_SCHEMA =>'AIM_DBA',
    object_name =>'EMP_DATA_I',
    policy_name =>'PROTECT_AIM_DBA_SCHEMA_TABLE',
    audit_condition=>'AIM_DBA.AUDITIF=1',
    statement_types =>'UPDATE,DELETE');
end;
/
```

But when running sql statement to  check audit policy functionality getting following error:

```
delete EMP_DATA_I
*
ERROR at line 1:
ORA-00905: missing keyword
ORA-06512: at "AIM_DBA.AUDITIF", line 5
```

Answer (score 1):

The result of the context call appears to be null, so you're attempting to run

```
explain plan for
```

as a complete statement, with nothing after the `for` ; which will throw that error.

From [the DBMS_FGA docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/arpls/DBMS_FGA.html#GUID-BE9BD27B-14AB-4742-B4C5-4A945349DC64):

> The *audit_condition* must be a boolean expression that can be evaluated using the values in the row being inserted, updated, or deleted. The expression can also use functions, such as the USER or SYS_CONTEXT functions.
>
> The expression must not combine conditions using operators such as AND and OR. audit_condition can be NULL (or omitted), which is interpreted as TRUE, but it cannot contain the following elements:
>
> - Subqueries or sequences
> - The following attributes of the USERENV namespace when accessed using the SYS_CONTEXT function:
>
>   - CURRENT_SQL
>   - CURRENT_SQL_LENGTH
>   - CURRENT_BIND
> - Any use of the pseudo columns LEVEL, PRIOR, or ROWNUM.

And in [the `sys_context` docs](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/SYS_CONTEXT.html#GUID-B9934A5D-D97B-4E51-B01B-80C76A5BD086__G1513460):

> `CURRENT_SQL` returns the first 4K bytes of the current SQL that triggered the fine-grained auditing event. ... You can specify these attributes only inside the event handler for the fine-grained auditing feature.

So you can use that in `handler_module` function, but not in a function you call as part of the `audit_condition`.

Comment: I want to limiting audit trail generation in FGA_LOG$ , currently each and every update, delete   statement getting captured in FGA_LOG$, I want capture only those sql which don't have "Where" clause.

Comment: Do you have any workaround or solution for this